# Can't connect to one EC2 instance in the same security group of another accessible EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, inbound-security-rule

I have two EC2 instances running Windows. They are both in the same security group which allows for all outgoing ports, but only RDP ports from my IP. What I can't figure out is that both, to my examination, have the same security and networking settings, but one connects through RDP but the other one doesn't.

Any suggestions for settings to look at?

Comment: **Side-note:** Multiple instances are not "in the same security group". Security Groups apply their rules individually on each resource. Therefore, Security Groups can _apply_ to multiple instances, but the instances are not "in" the same group. The Security Group would still need rules that allow the Group to talk to itself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That is an important detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few attempts of download the .rdp file, checking the inbound rules, running `nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com` to see my IP just to make sure I wasn't going crazy.

Ultimately what solved the problem was restarting my own computer and running the .rdp file. Not sure why, but maybe my computer was sending stale configuration data.